# Accessing all taxonomy terms from one specific vocabulary through url

Tags: taxonomy-terms, path-aliases, uri

I want do display all my terms from one vocabulary over drupals pathauto url scheme.
So f.e. I have example.com/taxonomy/term/314 or after pathauto: example.com/screwdriver/slot or example.com/screwdriver/torx. This works good.

But if I visit example.com/screwdriver, this page doesn't exist.

Actually I'm kind of puzzled, that this is not working out of the box. Do I really have to implement a custom module for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a functionality made for that particular page? Is that a term namde, a node or a view? Any kind of entity? Because if it is not, nothing will show up, obviously. Create a view page showing all taxonomy terms within that vocabulary. Taxonomy pages are for taxonomy terms only, not for taxonomy vocabulary based on some url scheme.

Comment: Is there really no possibility to build this functionality without using the super fat views module?

Comment: You need content on that page. A piece of content is an entity that can be a views page, a node, a term, a comment or a user. There are ways to add content programatically, but you need to write your own code.
Other than that, I dont see Views super fat. With proper customization, it works great, loads really fast and it offers limitless possibilities.