# Rewrite query string for exposed taxonomy filter

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, uri

I have this page: https://www.meubelentheo.be/catalogus

On the top of this page, just below the title you will see links such as Babykamer, Bureau, Decoratie etc.

These are taxonomy terms in an exposed filter. I use the Views module together with Better exposed filter.

If you click on the first term Babykamer, you will see the URL changes to https://www.meubelentheo.be/catalogus?field_portfolio_tags_tid=34

What I want to achieve: rewrite the part after the ? to something like `?term=babykamer` or even better, rewrite the whole querystring to `catalogus/babykamer`

I tried the Query paramters to URL module and this indeed rewrites the URL to but this is not what I want. I want the taxonomy term name to be shown in the URL.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using pathauto, maybe? See [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/125764/accessing-all-taxonomy-terms-from-one-specific-vocabulary-through-url).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this look by using Contextual Filters instead of an exposed filter in Views. But this approach will involve several changes. In a nutshell you would need to:

1. The list of tags on top would need to be a different (taxonomy) Views, embedded in the Header area of your catalogus View using `Global: View area`. In the taxonomy view, you will need to rewrite the output of the Taxonomy field (use "Rewrite results" in the taxonomy field) to a link that points to `/catalogus/[field_portfolio_tags]`
2. Add a Contextual Filter to your catalogus View. Be sure to add the taxonomy field `Portfolio tags` to the list of fields in this View (you can hide it if you don't want it to display for every single product). Choose the taxonomy `Content: Portfolio tags`. Choose **Display all results** in **When filter value is not in URL**. In **WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS IN THE URL OR A DEFAULT IS PROVIDED**  choose **Specify validation criteria**. Validator: taxonomy term. Filter value type: term name converted to Term Id.

When you click on a taxonomy term in the embedded header View you will be redirected to /catalogus/name_of_tag. The Contextual Filter will assure that only products with that tag will be shown.

This should be it!

Answer (score 0):

The use case "Filter my view results with the Term Name in my url" we are discussing here can easily be achieved with "Contextual filter by term ID" + the very old, stable and light "URL alias" feature. Easier and faster.

Please do note also on Drupal 8  this is even more complicated ([follow on Druapl.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/2645442))

Url alias will make you work easier on both D8 and D7

[image]